# Get key and value from firebase push notification

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, key, react-native-firebase

I have an react-native App (android) to receive push notification from firebase console.

[image: from firebase console]

Is there any function in react-native-firebase can get key and value (custom data) from push notification message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your notification listener try to extract your custom keys/values from the `data` object

```
const { data } = notificationOpen.notification;
alert(data.myKey);
```

Comment: yea i get it by using firebase.notifications, thanks
`const notificationOpen: NotificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
const notification: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
var jsondata = notification.data`